# Update from the datagridview to the database creates no responding and there is no result of that update in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ado.net, dbf

Dear All Master,

I did an Update from datagridview to the database making it not responding and there was no result of that update in VB.NET. Is there something wrong with my code because the update results are not there and also when I do the button event it makes the form not responding whether because the record line there are 1200 records.

Thanks

```
    Public Function GetConnectionString() As String
        Dim strCon As String = "Provider=ApolloOLEDB9.ApolloOLEDB9;Data Source=|DataDirectory\;Persist Security Info=False;"
        Return strCon
    End Function
    Private conn As New ApolloConnection(GetConnectionString())
 Private Sub DisplayProvider()
        Dim adapter As New ApolloDataAdapter()
        adapter.SelectCommand = New ApolloCommand("Select PNM,NOD,ITM,CIU From RPD", conn)
        conn.Open()
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        DataGrid1.DataSource = dt
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
Private Sub update()
        Dim comm As New ApolloCommand("UPDATE RPD SET CIU=@CIU WHERE PNM=@PNM AND NOD=@NOD AND ITM=@ITM", conn)
        'Add parameters
        comm.Parameters.Add(New ApolloParameter("@CIU", ApolloDBType.Numeric))
        comm.Parameters.Add(New ApolloParameter("@PNM", ApolloDBType.Character))
        comm.Parameters.Add(New ApolloParameter("@NOD", ApolloDBType.Character))
        comm.Parameters.Add(New ApolloParameter("@ITM", ApolloDBType.Character))
        'Open connection
        conn.Open()
        'Update data
        For item As Integer = 0 To DataGrid1.Rows.Count - 1
            comm.Parameters("@CIU").Value = DataGrid1.Rows(item).Cells(3).Value
            comm.Parameters("@PNM").Value = DataGrid1.Rows(item).Cells(0).Value
            comm.Parameters("@NOD").Value = DataGrid1.Rows(item).Cells(1).Value
            comm.Parameters("@ITM").Value = DataGrid1.Rows(item).Cells(2).Value
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        'Close connection
        conn.Close()
        'Display data
        DisplayProvider()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        update()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Well, hard to know.  Maybe as you've tagged dbf, that might be as fast as it can go although I would seriously doubt that.  Anyway, couple suggestions.  1) ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of records updated, worth checking.  2) Use a for each loop to iterate collections. 3)  You use a DataAdapter to read DB, why not use one for updating?

Comment: You're doing it all wrong. You should be using the same data adapter to save all the changes from the `DataTable` with a single call to `Update`. There are lots of examples around of using data adapters to save data. [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872)'s one of my own.